# Entity framework split DATETIME to sort by TIME only

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm running a query on table which contains a DATETIME column where I want to sort results by TIME only and ignore the date. I've put together the following query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Id, s.SubmittedDate, s.CheckId, s.RestaurantId, s.StaffName, s.CustomerEmail, s.TableNumber 
FROM Survey s
ORDER BY  DATEPART (hh,s.submittedDate) ASC, DATEPART(mi,s.submittedDate) ASC
```

The problem with this query is that it generates the error `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified`. However, I cannot add the order by fields to the field list in the query as it doesn't exist on the Survey Entity that Entity Framework maps the results to.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a Java background, I assumed that Entity Framework would complain if the results returned fields that did not exist on the entity. I tried it and Entity Framework does not complain and it works as expected.

My final working query is;

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Id, s.SubmittedDate, s.CheckId, s.RestaurantId, s.StaffName, s.CustomerEmail, s.TableNumber, DATEPART(hh, s.submittedDate) as hrs, DATEPART(mi, s.submittedDate) as mins 
FROM Survey s
ORDER BY hrs, mins ASC
```